# Buscador interno con acentos

Tags: html, jquery, firebase

quisiera poder mejorar un buscador interno para que pueda leer palabras con acentos de una base de datos sin necesidad de escribir los acentos en el buscador. Tengo otro buscador que si puedes buscar palabras sin acentos. Por ejemplo: busco mi nombre"Rubén". En la base de datos consta como "Rubén" pero en el buscador voy a escribir "ruben". Espero me podáis ayudar.

Os paso el código del search que quiero mejorar:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Buscador interno</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #result {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   max-width:870px;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 400px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 1001;
  }
  .link-class:hover{
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">

   <div align="center">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Buscar ciudad" class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");


  $.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {

   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.ciudad.search(expression) != -1 )
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.ciudad+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.provincia+'</span></li>');

    }
   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
</script>
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "ciudad":"Ruben",
    "image": "https://www.madridiario.es/fotos/1/Los_pueblos_mA_s_bonitos_de_Madrid.jpg",
    "provincia":"MADRID"
  },

    {
    "ciudad":"Rubn",
    "image": "https://www.madridiario.es/fotos/1/Los_pueblos_mA_s_bonitos_de_Madrid.jpg",
    "provincia":"MADRID"
  }

]
```

Os paso el código del search que funciona sin escribir el acento en el search:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">  
  <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/autocomplete-ok.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div>
  <form>

  <input id="developer">
  </form>
</div>



<div>
  <form>

  <input id="developer2">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

$( function() {
        var names = [ "Jörn", "Scott ", "John2" ];

```
    var accentMap = {
      "á": "a",
      "ö": "o"
    };
    var normalize = function( term ) {
      var ret = "";
      for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
        ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
      }
      return ret;
    };

    $( "#developer" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
          value = value.label || value.value || value;
          return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
        }) );
      }
    });
  } );

  $( function() {
    var names = [ "1", "2 ", "3" ];

    var accentMap = {
      "á": "a",
      "ö": "o"
    };
    var normalize = function( term ) {
      var ret = "";
      for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
        ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
      }
      return ret;
    };

    $( "#developer2" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
          value = value.label || value.value || value;
          return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
        }) );
      }
    });
  } );
```

La función:

$( function() {
        var names = [ "Jörn", "Scott ", "John2" ];

```
    var accentMap = {
      "á": "a",
      "ö": "o"
    };
    var normalize = function( term ) {
      var ret = "";
      for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
        ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
      }
      return ret;
    };

    $( "#developer" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
          value = value.label || value.value || value;
          return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
        }) );
      }
    });
  } );

  $( function() {
    var names = [ "1", "2 ", "3" ];

    var accentMap = {
      "á": "a",
      "ö": "o"
    };
    var normalize = function( term ) {
      var ret = "";
      for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
        ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
      }
      return ret;
    };

    $( "#developer2" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
          value = value.label || value.value || value;
          return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
        }) );
      }
    });
  } );
```

Comment: en la base de datos he puesto 1 como "Ruben" y otro como "Rubn" = es en realidad "Rubén".

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos estás utilizando?  Creo que sería mucho mejor si este tema de mayúsculas/minúsculas  y acentos los manejás con collations en la base de datos.

Comment: es firebase, por eso he enlazado a un data.json

Comment: para ver el autocomplete creas un archivo html con el código y otro data.json en una carpeta js

el autocomplete está tirando de el archivo data.js para probar internamente.

Comment: data.json.   perdón.

Comment: la ruta sería: js/data.json

Answer (score 1):

puedes utilizar esta funcion a ver si te sirve:

```js
function as(s){
 let a=["á","é","í","ó","ú","a","e","i","o","u"];
 let str="";
 for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
  let tmp = s[i];
    for(let x=0; x < a.length-5; x++){
       if(tmp.toLowerCase() == a[x]){ tmp === tmp.toLowerCase() ? tmp=a[x+5] : tmp=a[x+5].toUpperCase();}
    }
    str+=tmp;
  }
  return str;
}
alert(`${as("RECÓRTALO")} ${as("suprímelo")} ${as("inútil! xD")}`);
// o modo avanzado:
function adv_as(s) {
return s
       .normalize('NFD')
       .replace(/([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+/gi,"$1")
       .normalize();
}
console.log(`${adv_as("RECÓRTALO")} ${adv_as("suprímelo")} ${adv_as("inútil! xD")}`);
```

advance mode fuente:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize

Comment: Gracias voy a probarlo a ver si funciona.